# How to call pointer to function defined in typedef struct

Tags: c, function-pointers

what is wrong with the following code?
parseCounter1() and parseCounter1() below are two functions.
I put their pointers in `const OptionValueStruct` so that
they can be called accordingly when each element of option_values[]
are gone through:

```
typedef struct OptionValueStruct{  
    char counter_name[OPTION_LINE_SIZE];  
    int* counter_func;  
} OptionValueStruct_t;  

const OptionValueStruct option_values[] = {    
    {"Counter1", (*parseCounter1)(char*, char**)},  
    {"Counter2", (*parseCounter2)(char*, char**)},  
   };  

const OptionValueStruct *option = NULL;

for(int i = 0; i< sizeof(option_values)/sizeof(OptionValueStruct_t); i++){
    option = option_values + i ;  
    result = option->counter_func(opt_name, opt_val);  
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have declared your `counter_func` member to be a pointer to an int, not a function pointer , while you have something resembling a function pointer declaration in your `option values`. Here's what you want (assuming your return type is int )

```
typedef struct OptionValueStruct{
  char counter_name[OPTION_LINE_SIZE];
  int (*counter_func)(char*, char**);
} OptionValueStruct_t;

const OptionValueStruct_t option_values[] = {
  {"Counter1", parseCounter1},
  {"Counter2", parseCounter2},
};

for(int i = 0; i< sizeof(option_values)/sizeof(OptionValueStruct_t); i++){
  result = option_values[i]->counter_func(opt_name, opt_val); 
  // don't know what you relly want to do with result further on..
}
```

Comment: Is the colon (instead of semicolon) at the end of int (*counter_func)(char*, char**) a typo? or some special syntax?

Comment: No it was a typo

Answer (score 0):

If you are compiling as C code (as your tag suggests), then you should change the type of `option_values[]` and `option` to `OptionValueStruct_t`. In C++, however, this is OK.

Alternatively, you can eliminate the trailing `_t` from the custom type name.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 

the type of option_values[] is already OptionValueStruct_t and
the type of option is OptionValueStruct_t *. as I show in 
the original post. 

do you mean I should use struct OptionValueStruct{...},  
then use declaration struct OptionValueStruct option_value[]?

Comment: @lilili08 - at the time of writing this comment, the type of the two variables is `const OptionValueStruct` and not `const OptionValueStruct_t`. However, `OptionValueStruct` is the **tag** of the struct definition and not the name of the custom type (at the `typedef` statement). In C, a struct tag is NOT a new type. In C++, though, it is. Now, the tag and the custom type name can be the same, so you can remove the `_t` characters from the `typedef` statement and have the newly defined type to be `OptionValueStruct` so you can use it in further variable declarations.

Comment: @lilili08 -  If you are using the Visual C++, most probably the compilation is done as C++ code, so the compiler does not warn you about this. You can change the `Project Properties`/`Configuration Properties`/`C/C++`/`Advanced`/`Compile As` to `Compile as C code` so you know for sure you are C compliant.