# call function in typedef struct in C

Tags: c, function, struct

I found a similiar answer to my problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443877/how-to-call-pointer-to-function-defined-in-typedef-struct). But it is not working the way I expected.
So I have

```
void funcA(void) {
  // do sth.
}
void funcB(void) {
  // do sth.
}

typedef struct tasks {
    int val;
    void (*Start)(void);
} tasks;
```

and

```
const tasks tasklist[] = 
    {       
        {0, funcA},
        {3, funcB}
    };

for (i=0; i < task_cnt; i++ )     
    if (tasklist[i].val == 3)
        tasklist[i]->Start();
```

But at "...->Start();" compiler says "expression must have pointer type".

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You access `Start` the same way you access `val` — with a dot: `tasklist[i].Start()`.

Answer (score 2):

you have to use `tasklist[i].Start(`) instead of `tasklist[i]->Start()`

this is due to the fact that **a.b** is used for accessing member b of object a while **a->b** access a member b of object pointed to by a.

you can have the full explanation [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++#Member_and_pointer_operators)